# Need to pass data from a row to a function to generate the text for anchor tag

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, primeng

Below is the html table from PrimeNg, I would like to display what getDisplayPaymentStatus is returning into the anchor tag and would like to enable the anchor tag when the status is 'Due'

```
<p-table [value]="repayPlanPayments" sortMode="multiple" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="400px"
              styleClass="ui-noborder">

              <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                  <th pSortableColumn="status">Status <p-sortIcon field="status"></p-sortIcon>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template pTemplate="body"  let-RepayPlanPaymentModel>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                     <a [ngClass]="{'isDisabled':  !isDue}" (click)="makePayment()">{{getDisplayPaymentStatus(RepayPlanPaymentModel)}}</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>
            </p-table>
```

Typescript:
Depending on the below logic isDue and the text to display is set

```
 isDue: boolean;
  public getDisplayPaymentStatus(repayPlanPaymentModel: RepayPlanPaymentModel): string {
    if (repayPlanPaymentModel.datePaymentReceived) {
      this.isDue = false;
      return 'Paid';
    }
    var payableDate = new Date();
    payableDate.setDate(payableDate.getDate() + 15);
    if (repayPlanPaymentModel.repayDueDate >= payableDate) {
      this.isDue = false;
      return '';
    }
    this.isDue = true;
    return 'Due';
  }
```

SCSS
Below is the style

```
a.isDisabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

[Below is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lbwt.png)

Comment: Error I am getting

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.